# Generating PDF from SVG with background-image

Tags: image, pdf, ubuntu, svg, background

### Problem description:

I use the [Highcharts API](http://www.highcharts.com) to render SVG. When I convert it with a tool like [**rsvg-convert**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/rsvg-convert.1.html) (I've also tried imagemagick, graphicsmagick and inkscape) the SVG is rendered perfectly into the PDF container. The only thing I'm missing in the generated PDF is the background-image.

I can produce PNG/JPG without any problems by converting the SVG to a transparent PNG and then melting this with a background-image. Of course I could just throw such a melted image into a PDF container but that's not what I want.

I need to **keep the SVG as a transparent vectorized image** with a JPG or PNG as **background-image** and the whole construct **in a PDF container**.

### Solution approaches:

#### Embedded as absolute URL as background-image inline-style:

```
<svg version="1.1" style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode',
 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill:
 #444444; background-image: url(http://an.absolute.url/image.jpg);"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="723" height="375">
...
</svg>
```

*Result: renders without background-image*

#### Embedded as absolute URL as image tag within SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" ...>
  <defs>
    <image xlink:href="http://an.absolute.url/image.jpg"
           x="0" y="0" width="723" height="375"
           preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
    ...
  </defs>
  ...
</svg>
```

*Result: renders without background-image*

#### Embedded as base64-encoded background-image as inline-style:

```
<svg version="1.1" style="font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode',
 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(68, 68, 68); fill:
 #444444; background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAlgCWAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wgARCAGQAmwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAwEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAwQFAgYBAAcJ/8QAGQEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQF/9oADAMBAAIQAxAAAAH+7JxvNfA2YShQjqXEfWZY8+4HlgNAQMvR4ujtYzAMK0Ws+/...inDlwJRZerdtbi5TYwq7PRqadq//9k=);"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="723" height="375">
...
</svg>
```

*Result: renders without background-image*

### Question:

Does anybody know how to solve this on an Ubuntu shell? I'm using PHP's exec function to execute shell commands and I can modify the SVG before it's passed to the shell execution process. Please forgive me that I don't provide more information now, I'd rather like to keep the question itself as short as possible but answer your questions in detail.

Comment: Use a technology that supports SVG transfomation into PDF. Most XSL FO technologies do.

Comment: Great idea, Kevin! Thank you very much for this inspiration, I will try it out.